# How can I add a custom attribute to the customer table?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I seach many answer that nerver success.
My last try is this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255460/how-to-add-a-customer-attribute-in-a-custom-module-using-declarative-schema-in-m)
This is my code in my `Module/Setup/Patch/Data`

```
<?php
namespace Mus\Hello\Setup\Patch\Data;


use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute  implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    protected $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ){
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":1}',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 120,
                'position' => 120,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'system' => false,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number'
        );

        $attribute->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]
        );

        $attribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }
}
```

I try to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`,but it doesn't work.
I can't saw the field in the admin customer create table.
How can I solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Mus\Hello\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply(): self
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        $this->createCustomerAttribute(
            attribute_code,
            [
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute name',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 700,
                'source' => Boolean::class,
            ],
            [
                'default_value' => 0,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'checkout_register',
                    'customer_account_create',
                ],
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add simply code and show in eav attribute table:-

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }   
      
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
          
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'approve_account', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Approve Account',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,

        ]);
          
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'approve_account')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],//you can use other forms also
        ]);
          
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**`THANKS.`**